# Tensorflow - Error while fetching data_set from MNIST_data

Tags: tensorflow

Please assist me in resolving this issue, I am a beginner in TF, it might be a silly mistake I am doing here -
I am getting below error while executing these two lines :

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rishabh/PycharmProjects/TF/ReadDatasetFromMNIST.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist import read_data_sets
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import distributions
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distributions/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.distributions.python.ops.estimator import *
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distributions/python/ops/estimator.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.head import _compute_weighted_loss
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import estimators
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/__init__.py", line 297, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.dnn import DNNClassifier
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import dnn_linear_combined
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io import data_feeder
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io.dask_io import extract_dask_data
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/dask_io.py", line 26, in <module>
    import dask.dataframe as dd
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .core import (DataFrame, Series, Index, _Frame, map_partitions,
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 36, in <module>
    pd.computation.expressions.set_use_numexpr(False)
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'computation'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/766), you're using an outdated version of `dask`.

If you're using Anaconda, run `conda update dask`, otherwise run `pip install dask --upgrade` to upgrade to the latest `dask` version available. This should fix the pandas error.

Comment: Thanks a lot GPhio!